# Swashbuckle.AspNetCore stop using allOf

Tags: .net-core, swashbuckle, autorest

I am using autorest to on my swagger.json file.
I have run into a problem where autorest does not like my swagger.json file.

The issue is that the swagger.json file contains

```
"parentType": {
  "allOf": [
    {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/MyClass"
    }
  ]
}
```

It works as

```
    "parentType": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/MyClass"
    }
```

Is there anyway I can get swashbuckle to generate the later code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a breaking change from RC5 of swashbuckle to v5

https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1488

Answer (score 0):

In newer version of `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore` for disabling `allof` you can remove
`options.UseAllOfToExtendReferenceSchemas();` in Swagger configuration in `Startup` or `Program.cs`. as you can see in new comments on https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1488 and https://github.com/unchase/Unchase.Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Extensions/issues/13